# Painting Text on Model

Tags: post-processing

For a model that has raised text on it, how do go about painting the very top layer of text, to make it stand out from the background? Lets say I printed the whole model the same color, what type of paint would work well, and not get on the background too?

Here's an example of a model that has raised text: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3025280

Comment: Use a firm (as opposed to spongey) roller..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't provide any dimensions or sizes, but...

Assuming that the text is sufficiently elevated from the rest of the model, you could use a firm solid (as opposed to soft and spongey) roller, of an appropriate width.

This should enable you to paint just the text without getting paint on the rest of the model.

- If the text is small and in a "valley" or groove, then a narrow roller would be required, in order to avoid the surface either side of the text.
- If the text is not on a flat, or smooth surface, then a small diameter roller might be required.
- If you can't find a tiny paint roller, you could *[jerry-rig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jury_rigging)* one using a paper clip and a roller wheel from an old cassette tape

Answer (score 1):

The technique you look for is *drybrushing* and not dependant on a specific type of color, as long as it can be applied with a brush.

An alternative technique might be carefully applying glue and leaf metal.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to print stencil for the text. Basically flat thin plate with text holes in it. Just cover your model with it and only text will be painted through the hole. In this way you could do it rough, fast or like Mr Bean did.